# Can you import posts from Instagram?

Tags: internet

I'm developing an app that users can connect to their Instagram account. Users will have an option to import their posts from their profile feed.

1. With the user's permission, can I show posts from the user's Instagram profile to display in my app's user's profile?
2. Do I have to indicate that the post from imported from Instagram? This could be Instagram's logo in some corner.